# How to differentiate StartUp screens in Xamarin Forms Shell

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have registration/login section as well main content.

Main content has tabbar section (down tabs), but I want to only show those tabs in main sectiom. registration/login section dont have.
First, in my App.cs I need to check if user exists (credentials from secure store), and on based what my api returns as an answer, I need to show to user correct page (some step in registration where he stopped last time, or if are credentials OK, to redirect im to main sector with down tabs)

I setup my AppShell as follows:

```
    <ShellItem Route="login">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate login:Page1}" />
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate login:Page2}" />
    </ShellItem>

    <ShellItem Route="register">

        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate register:RegisterPage1}" />
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate register:RegisterPage2}" />
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate register:RegisterPage3}" />
    </ShellItem>


    <TabBar Route="main">
        <Tab Title="Activity" Icon="tab_feed.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate postlogin:ActivityPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Invest" Icon="tab_about.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate postlogin:InvestPage}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
```

Know I want somehow to tell codebehind of AppShell, to based on response of my api to go to specific routing page. I tried something like:

```
public AppShell()
        {
            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//register");
            });
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

But I have null reference exception. 
Do you have maybe better architectural solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should treat the Login and registration pages as separate from the shell. In other words, when app launches, check to see if the user needs to login/register. If so, push the login and/or registration page as a modal page, covering the Shell interface. Once finished with login/registration, then pop the modal page and you will be in your Shell with tabs.

Alternately, you can assign the `Application.MainPage` to your login or registration page when the app launches, and then when complete, reassign `Application.MainPage` to the `AppShell`, e.g.:

```
MainPage = new LoginPage();
// Authenticated!! - now open the shell
MainPage = new AppShell();
```

UPDATE: Though there is no reason I can think of to make sure the login/registration page is "in the shell," especially since it was stated that they do not want the tabs when the regitstration/login pages are being displayed, the problem with the code in the opening question is that they are calling Shell.Current during the AppShell constructor. You can probably avoid that error by adding an `await Task.Delay(500)` to let the AppShell finish constructing (and you should probably call `InitializeComponent` first), e.g.:

```
public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(500);
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//register");
        });

    }
```

However that is really against best practices that advises against launching async methods from constructors. Here is a blog post on an alternative: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html

e.g. do something like:

```
public sealed class MyClass
{
  private MyData asyncData;
  private MyClass() { ... }

  private async Task<MyClass> InitializeAsync()
  {
    asyncData = await GetDataAsync();
    return this;
  }

  public static Task<MyClass> CreateAsync()
  {
    var ret = new MyClass();
    return ret.InitializeAsync();
  }
}

public static async Task UseMyClassAsync()
{
  MyClass instance = await MyClass.CreateAsync();
  ...
}
```

Comment: yes, but my question was how to implement in a shell view? should I then have multiple AppShell's classes or?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with the following and enjoy :)

```
InitializeComponent();
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                await GoToAsync("//register");
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, you don't need to have separate `login/registration` from `Shell`. It will simply load based on how it is placed within `AppShell`. Then through the preferences you can say where you want to navigate from the beginning.

I have this working in one of my projects.

AppShell.cs:

```
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        RegisterRoutes();

        bool mainLogin = Preferences.ContainsKey(Settings.RememberLogin);

        if (mainLogin)
        {
            _ = GoToAsync("//Main");
        }
    }

    private void RegisterRoutes()
    {
        Routing.RegisterRoute("Register", typeof(RegisterPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute("Login", typeof(LoginPage));
    }
```

AppShell.xaml:

```
    <ShellItem Route="MainPage" Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled" 
               FlyoutItemIsVisible="False" Shell.ForegroundColor="White" Shell.TitleColor="White" 
               Shell.BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
    </ShellItem>

  <TabBar Route="Main">
        <Tab Title="Activity" Icon="tab_feed.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate postlogin:ActivityPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Invest" Icon="tab_about.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate postlogin:InvestPage}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
  <Button Command="{Binding GoToLoginPageCommand}" />
  <Button Command="{Binding GoToRegisterPageCommand}" />
```

When the login is correct:

```
Preferences.Set(Settings.RememberLogin, true);
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Main");
```

You will have to adapt it to your project.

Comment: Done, I hope it is better understood.

Comment: Yes it's better ! :)